What's with these patterns when graphing the least common multiple function?
When plotting the graph $y = lcm(x,k)$, where k is a natural number, I noticed that there are lines shooting off at different angles Desmos Screenshot. I also noticed that there are as many lines on each side of the y axis as there are factors of k. Does anyone know what exactly is going on here? There must be some significance to the angle of these lines right?

Hint: $lcm(x,k) =  \frac{k }{\gcd(x, k)} x$. So, we're going to get a bunch of lines through the origin. How many lines do we get?

@CalvinLin There are as many lines through the origin as there are factors of $k$. OOOOHHHHH I GET IT. Since $gcd(x, k)$ will always return a factor a k, there are that many distinct "slopes" that can be graphed. Super cool stuff!

Yup pretty much. With that formula, you can also analyze other characteristics like the "density" of the dots. $\quad$ Can you add a short writeup of your understanding?

Yeah, for $k = 24$, you get lines with slopes of 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, and 24.

@CalvinLin Sure! $gcd(x, k)$ will by definition return a factor of k. Then, by plotting $gcd(x, k)$ over all real numbers x, we will see as many distinct y values as there are factors of k, and each will be a factor of k. When dividing $xk$ by these values,  we will get different slopes between $k/k = 1$ and $k/1 = k$.
